# ion-card background transparent white

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm wanting to leave an ion-card as in the image, with a transparent background but a bit white, so that I can still see the image in the background. Could someone help me on how to do this?

I'm looking for an effect like in this image:

[image: image to demonstrate effect]

I'm using following code:

```
<ion-card class="cardconteudo">

    <ion-card-header>
     CARD HEADER
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
     CARD CONTENT
    </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
```

SCSS:

```
.cardconteudo {     
    float: unset !important;       
}    
.contentclass {
    background-image: url('../../assets/imgs/mammajamma.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 110%;
    background-position: 0% 14%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following SCSS:

```
.cardconteudo {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

This solution leverages rgba which is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp). Following syntax:

> rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)

where alpha defines *the opacity as a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque)*.

---

So we're using a white background (red, green and blue set to max) and set it to be half-transparent (alpha = 0.5). Feel free to adjust the alpha value accordingly to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.